# function not working after import firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

After trying to import the classes and functions for firebase the folowing function never works, it does not matter if is on the index or like in this case on a diferent js file the function that goes after returns the following error.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: ValidateEmail is not defined**

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

function ValidateEmail(inputText)
{
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
if(inputText.match(mailformat))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
```

validateEmail is being used here

```
function logIn(){
            var email = document.getElementById("emailLogin").value;
            var pass = document.getElementById("passLogin").value;

            if(email.length == 0 || pass.length == 0){
                alert("Correo o contraseña invalido!!");
            }else{
                if(ValidateEmail(email)){
                    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then((userCredential)=>{
                        var user = userCredential.user;
                    })
                    .catch((error)=>{
                        var errorCode = error.code;
                        var errorMessage = error.message;
                        alert(errorCode+" "+errorMessage);
                    });
                }else{
                    alert("El correo utilizado es invalido!!")
                }
            }
        }
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: can you show the code snippet where you are using this ValidateEmail method?

Comment: did you import the ValidateEmail method before using this method? also please mention which code base is this?